# Performing Calculations with Modules in Visual Basic

Tags: vb.net, module

I am writing a program for my Visual Basic class that is supposed to be able to calculate the final total price for items selected from one list box and added to another. 2 of the items have sales tax that must be added into the final price. The program also has a Module that is supposed to be used to keep record of all taxes and is used to do all tax-related functions.

Here is the most current code.

```
Option Strict On
Public Class Form1

Private Sub btnAdd_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles btnAdd.Click
    If (txtQuantity.Text = "") Then
        MessageBox.Show("Please enter a quantity for the item you selected")
    ElseIf Not Integer.TryParse(txtQuantity.Text, CInt(txtQuantity.Text)) Then
        MessageBox.Show("The quantity entered is not numeric. Please add a numeric quantity.")
        Exit Sub
    Else
        lstPurchased.Items.Add(txtQuantity.Text & " " & lstSale.Text)
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub btnCalculate_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles btnCalculate.Click
    Dim int As Integer
    Dim total As Double = 0

    For i As Integer = 0 To lstPurchased.Items.Count - 1
        Dim lst() As String = lstPurchased.Items(i).ToString.Split({CChar(" ")}, 2)
        Integer.TryParse(lst(0), int)
        total += TaxesModule.SalesTax(int, lst(1))
    Next
    MessageBox.Show(CStr(FormatCurrency(total)))
End Sub

Private Sub btnClear_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles btnClear.Click
    lstPurchased.Items.Clear()
    txtQuantity.Clear()
End Sub

End Class
```

And the most recent code for the module

```
Option Strict On

Module TaxesModule
Private Const DONUT_TAX As Decimal = CDec(0.083)
Private Const RAISIN_TAX As Decimal = CDec(0.02)
Private Const SS_TAX As Decimal = CDec(0.062) ' <-- you are not using this

Public Function SalesTax(ByVal Quantity As Integer, ByVal item As String) As Double
    Dim TotalWithSalesTax As Double
    If item = "Wheat Bread" Then
        TotalWithSalesTax += (Quantity * 1.15)
    ElseIf item = "White Bread" Then
        TotalWithSalesTax += (Quantity * 1.05)
    ElseIf item = "Donuts" Then
        TotalWithSalesTax += (Quantity * (0.5 * DONUT_TAX) + (Quantity * 0.5))
    ElseIf item = "Raisins" Then
        TotalWithSalesTax += (Quantity * (0.25 * RAISIN_TAX) + (Quantity * 0.25))
    End If
    Return TotalWithSalesTax
End Function

End Module
```

As the code is written now, the only problem I'm having is that the TotalWithSalesTax for "Raisins" is not calculating correctly. For example, if I select "Raisins" from the list box and add it with a quantity of 1 to the other list box, the total that is displayed in the message box is $0.00.

I'm starting to think the issue is with the following section of code:

```
For i As Integer = 0 To lstPurchased.Items.Count - 1
        Dim lst() As String = lstPurchased.Items(i).ToString.Split({CChar(" ")}, 2)
```

Because I have tried making changes such as

```
For i As Integer = 1 ...
```

And that caused both Donuts and Raisins to give me a total of $0.00 in the message box. So I'm wondering if maybe how the count is set up is not allowing it to go through the entire list, but I don't know how to fix that?

I'm still really new to Visual Basic, and programming in general really and this is my first time working with modules. Can anybody help me figure out what I'm doing wrong, so I can move onto other parts of the program?

Comment: I think you should grab a basic programming book and start reading again. concentrate bit more on variable scopes and `If` statements. You are having a lot of problems in your code.

Comment: Oh yeah, I'm sure there are lots of problems, I've been working with this code and have taken things out, put different things in, went back to some of the older things, etc and am not sure that I got everything out that I intended to yet. I do I messed something up when I started trying to add in the stuff from the module because before I added that, everything at least calculated the way it should before tax was added in.

Comment: To start with remove `Public FinalTotal As Double` or change it to private (you will need to fix code after this). What do you mean with `If item = "Wheat Bread" Then .. ElseIf item = "White Bread"` ? how is it possible. Convert all your variables to `Private`. Don't use Public variables as far as possible, it is pure evil.

Comment: Wheat Bread, White Bread, Donuts, and Raisins are all items on the lstSale list box. Donuts and Raisins are the only 2 items with a sales tax that has to be added to them. The main reason I was using Public variables is because some of the variables are used in this form and in the module. Like I said, I've never used modules before, we haven't even gone over them in class and the textbook is of no help whatsoever.

Comment: sry for the `if` statement mis-read the code, basically your public variables are causing the problem, I can try to fix it, but i may be wrong as i didn't fully understand the code.

Comment: No problem, my professor doesn't always give the best instructions, so it's usually kind of hard to explain to other people what we're supposed to do. And the fact that I've redone bits and pieces of this code doesn't help either.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49200/discussion-between-bansi-and-beth-tanner)

Comment: **WHY** does the tax stuff have to go into a module? they would work perfectly fine as a function in the form.  a) why `CInt(Quantity)` in btnAdd click? it is already an int.  b) the calc button needs to test the purchase not the TryParse (which just needs to be done once)  I think the wrong answer is this faulty IF block - it is always selling Wheat Bread.  Use a block like you do in the SalesTax function - you want to check what is being bought, not if the Quan will parse.  Most of what is wring is in btnCalculate...start with `FinalTotal = 0` so you dont accumulate

Comment: Because that's what the professor wants ha. To me it'd be so much simpler to just do it within the code of the form itself, but I think with each program he tries to implement something new, this week it's modules ha.

Comment: So, when should I do the TryParse?

Comment: This isn't even the end of the program, there are still two other things it has to do besides this, but I'm hoping that if I can understand this part, it'll make the other 2 things fairly simple. We'll see.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have modified your code, hope this is what you want. Added comment in the code. Note i have removed all Public variables.

```
Public Class Form1

    Private Sub btnAdd_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles btnAdd.Click
        If (txtQuantity.Text = "") Then
            MessageBox.Show("Please enter a quantity for the item you selected")
        ElseIf Not Integer.TryParse(txtQuantity.Text, txtQuantity.Text) Then
            MessageBox.Show("The quantity entered is not numeric. Please add a numeric quantity.")
            Exit Sub
        Else
            lstPurchased.Items.Add(txtQuantity.Text & " " & lstSale.Text)
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub btnCalculate_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles btnCalculate.Click
        Dim int As Integer
        Dim total As Double = 0
        'you have to loop through the list to calculate the total
        ' hope this is what you want
        For i As Integer = 0 To lstPurchased.Items.Count - 1
            ' We split the list item into the quantity and the item name
            Dim lst() As String = lstPurchased.Items(i).ToString.Split({CChar(" ")}, 2)
            'lst(1) contains the item name
            Integer.TryParse(lst(0), int)
            total += TaxesModule.SalesTax(int, lst(1))
        Next
        MessageBox.Show(CStr(FormatCurrency(total)))
    End Sub

    Private Sub btnClear_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles btnClear.Click
        lstPurchased.Items.Clear()
        txtQuantity.Clear()
    End Sub

End Class
```

The module

```
Module TaxesModule
    Private Const DONUT_TAX As Decimal = CDec(0.083)
    Private Const RAISIN_TAX As Decimal = CDec(0.02)
    Private Const SS_TAX As Decimal = CDec(0.062) ' <-- you are not using this

    Public Function SalesTax(ByVal Quantity As Integer, ByVal item As String) As Double
        Dim TotalWithSalesTax As Double
        If item = "Wheat Bread" Then
            TotalWithSalesTax = (Quantity * 1.15)
        ElseIf item = "White Bread" Then
            TotalWithSalesTax = (Quantity * 1.05)
        ElseIf item = "Donuts" Then
            TotalWithSalesTax = (Quantity * (0.5 * DONUT_TAX) + (Quantity * 0.5))
        ElseIf item = "Raisins" Then
            TotalWithSalesTax = (Quantity * (0.25 * RAISIN_TAX) + (Quantity * 0.25))
        End If
        Return TotalWithSalesTax
    End Function

End Module
```

Comment: Everything seems to work except that it's not calculating the right total for "Raisins". If I add Raisins to the Purchased list, with a quantity of 1, the price that's displayed in the message box is $0.00. Other than that, this fixed everything.